# Find patients that develop a more severe disease

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `patient_details` that has id, diagnosis_date and diagnosis_code. A unique ID can have multiple entries meaning they were diagnosed with different diseases at different times.

GOAL: I want to see patients that eventually progress to having disease code 5.10. So I want to see patients who were first diagnosed with code 5 and then progress to diagnosis 5.10. I am not sure how to isolate the dates for each unique patient and see who went from an initial diagnosis of 5 to eventually 5.10. I ultimately just need the count of patients who go from diagnosis code 5 to 5.10

Example of table:

```
ID    |diagnosis_date|diagnosis_code
PT2073|2015-02-28    |5
PT2073|2019-02-28    |5.10
PT2013|2015-04-28    |1
PT2013|2017-02-11    |5
PT2013|2017-07-11    |5.10
```

Comment: So you want to get all patients with at least two data sets: one with 5 and one with 10. The dataset with 5 needs an earlier date than the dataset with 10?

Comment: Yes exactly! They can have other diagnoses but I only care if they had 5 first and then 10. I want to know how many had that progression.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
select id
from patient_details
group by id
having
    min(case when diagnosis_code = 5 then diagnosis_date end)
    < max(case when diagnosis_code = 5.1 then diagnosis_date end)
```

This will ensure that:

- the patient has at least one record with `diagnosis_code = 5` and another with `diagnosis_code = 10`
- the date they were first diagnosed with code `5` is less than the date they were last diagnosed `5.1`

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e384ee0e1010790b3596319194f4d5a2)**

Sample data:

```
id     | diagnosis_date | diagnosis_code
:----- | :------------- | -------------:
PT2073 | 2015-02-28     |           4.00
PT2073 | 2019-02-28     |           5.10
PT2013 | 2015-04-28     |           1.00
PT2013 | 2017-02-11     |           5.00
PT2013 | 2017-07-11     |           5.10
```

Results:

```
| id     |
| :----- |
| PT2013 |
```

Comment: This is just returning all the values for me for some reason

Comment: @Py.rookie89: I had a typo where I put `10` instead of `5.1` in the query. Apart from that, the query looks fine. I added a db fiddle to my answer for your reference.